# How to target intermediary Snakemake rule that contains wildcards

Tags: snakemake

I have a workflow that, very simplified for this question, looks as follows:

```yaml
rule all:
    input: multiext("final",".a",".b",".c",".d")

rule final_cheap:
    input: "intermediary.{ext}"
    output: "final.{ext}"
    #dummy for cheap but complicated operation
    shell: "cp {input} {output}"

rule intermediary_cheap:
    input: "start.{ext}"
    output: "intermediary.{ext}"
    #dummy for cheap complicated operation
    shell: "cp {input} {output}" 

rule start_expensive:
    output: "start.{ext}"
    #dummy for very expensive operation
    shell: "touch {output}"
```

There's a very expensive first step and two complicated steps that follow.

After I've run this workflow once with `snakemake -c1` I want to rerun the workflow but just from the intermediary rule onwards. How can I achieve this goal with command line flags?

`snakemake intermediary_cheap all` does not work, because `intermediary_cheap` contains wildcards, even though the inclusion of all really shows the values of the required wildcards.

Is there a command line flag that tells snakemake to run the rule and ignore all output from the rule `intermediary_cheap`, something like `snakemake all --forcerule=intermediary_cheap`? (I invented that `--forcerule` flag, it doesn't exist as far as I know.

The workaround I'm using right now is manually deleting the output of the rule `intermediary_cheap`, then forcing execution of the rule with `--force` and then running `rule all`, which notices that some upstream inputs have changed. But this requires knowledge of the precise file names that are produced, whereas knowledge of rules only would be preferable because it is at a higher level of abstraction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used it before but I think you want:

```
snakemake -c 1 --forcerun intermediary_cheap
```

```
  --forcerun [TARGET [TARGET ...]], -R [TARGET [TARGET ...]]
                        Force the re-execution or creation of the given rules
                        or files. Use this option if you changed a rule and
                        want to have all its output in your workflow updated.
                        (default: None)
```

Comment: You're a star! This is the solution. If you want all of the output to be produced, simply do as you suggested. If you want to just produce `final.a` say, add that on top: `snakemake -c1 --forcerun intermediary_cheap -- final.a `, the `--` is necessary, because we just want that, with the rule intermediary_cheap to be forced.
You can edit your answer if you want to include that. Thanks!